# How to organize drawable assets in order to have two "skins" in my Android app

Tags: android

I want my users to be able to switch between a red and blue layout.
I have two sets of `.png` files for the buttons and other parts of the UI.

At the moment I've put them all in the same folder and have named them using the following convention:

```
button_login_blue.png
button_login_red.png
```

When binding the views in the activity, I do the following

```
if (user.getSkin() == Skin.RED) {
    loginButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_login_red)
}
```

Is there a more ellegant way to do this? Is there a way to somehow include the different colors in the `Skin` enum, which at the moment looks like this:

```
public enum Skin {
    RED,
    BLUE
}
```

So that I can somehow polymorphicly dispatch the colors?

Can I create separate folders for the skins in the `res/drawable` folder?

Comment: Maybe you could have transparent images and add a dynamic filter on it.

Comment: Yeah that is what I proposed but it will happen in next iteration. For now we have the separate sets of pngs, so I want to find a way to organize them as skins

Comment: If you are using Android studio, you can easily achieve that by product flavor.

Comment: The user will be able to toggle a button and change their skin